# Can some one tell whether collection make use of polymorphism ?

Tags: java, collections, polymorphism

If yes please let me know how does collection make use of polymorphism concept

Comment: From Java 1.5 onwards all of Java collections are Generics, it is also one of the polymorphism

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: your question is too broad

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.Collection` is an interface; so is `java.util.List`. So when you have

```
class X {
  List<String> list;
}
```

and have a method somewhere else

```
void readX(X x) {
  x.list.add("you");
}
```

you are employing the principle of polymorphism that will call an appropriate implementation of the method `Collection#add`.

Comment: This example makes use of compile time polymorphism, can u give an example for run time polymorphism?

Comment: @Charan no, it makes use of runtime polymorphism. Compile-time polymorphism is Generics.

Comment: Ya your rite...understood now..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

Collections are indeed polymorphic: all collection classes in Java implement one or more *interfaces*, letting you swap in a new implementation if you program to collection's interface.

For example, if you define and use

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you can replace it with

```
List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

and the rest of the code would not need to change. Of course there would be consequences in timing if you try accessing elements in the middle of a linked list.